# ASP.NET Core MVC button visibility

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hiding multiple buttons I previously added to table cells. Is it possible to sequentially make it visible with a single button control? How can I do this with c#?

There are educational contents such as layout, html, css on the web but I could not find anything related to what I wanted to do. How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Sorry it's not quite clear what you mean. Are you asking how to show each button, one after the other, e.g. button 1 appears, then button 2 appears, then button 3 appears, etc?

Comment: this looks like a javascript-related issue. nothing to do with c# or asp.net

Comment: I want to hide the buttons I added to the table. I want to make the buttons visible with another button I added outside the table. This is possible with javascript, but I want to know if it can be done in c #.

Comment: @MuratKorkmaz c# is a server-side language, it can help you generate the HTML content (using some kind of complex template like Razor View or Razor Page). It has no control over your HTML buttons rendered on the client side (browser). If you want some magic of c# code doing some client task (replacing javascript), maybe try looking into the so-called `Blazor` app (a new featured supported in .net core). But then it is not `asp.net core mvc` anymore.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with c#,when click add button,you need to pass the data you want to pass the amount you want to show to action.Here is a demo:

View(TestTable.cshtml):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Amount > 0)
        {
            var count = 0;
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Amount / 5 + 1; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    @for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (count <=Model.Amount&&count<=Model.Buttons.Count)
                        {
                            <th><button>@Model.Buttons[5 * i + j]</button></th>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
<form method="post">
    <input hidden name="Amount" value="@Model.Amount">
    <input hidden name="Add" value="1">
    <button>Add</button>
</form>
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestTable(TableModel t)
        {
            List<string> l = new List<string> { "b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5" };
            
            TableModel table = new TableModel { Buttons = l ,Amount=0,Add=0};
            if (t.Add == 1 && t.Amount >= 0) {
                table.Amount = ++t.Amount;
            }
                return View(table);
        }
```

Model:

```
public class TableModel {
        public List<string> Buttons { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int Add { get; set; }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to know, what Was curious about.Thank you for your answer.